# How does Redux know that it's an action and the state when we mention 'action' and 'state', respectively, as reducer parameters?

Tags: redux

I am new to Redux and I am trying to understand its basic concepts. There is one thing I am not able to clearly understand.

I know that a reducer is a function and that there are two parameters that a reducer takes: the first one being a state and the second being an action. What confuses me is, how does Redux actually know that the second parameter is an action when we mention an action as a parameter?

I mean, when we just mention in a switch's case statement `action.type`, how does Redux know it's an action? And the same question for state. When we initialize `state={}`, how does Redux know that it's the state of the Redux store?

Comment: It's not really clear what you're asking - a function/library "knows" what function parameters are what because it's programmed that way / the documentation says so.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth so is it the order in which the parameters are sent that actually matters? I mean if we write the first parameter as something else other than state, even then that will be referring to the state? And is that the same case for action as well?

Comment: Remember you passed all this info to the store when you were creating your store, the reducers as combined reducers and also the default state, so the redux is able to deduce what is what...an action object is passed to the reducer for you to be able to handle different actions and they effect on state in different ways